# Unable to login to Heroku admin panel after successfully creating superuser

Tags: python, django, github, heroku

I am trying to create a superuser for a Django website that I have deployed on Heroku via Github. I did this locally by running the console locally for my Heroku app as shown in the image below. I followed the prompts after typing the command 'python manage.py createsuperuser' and got a message stating that the superuser was created successfully. However, when I opened the app again and trying to access the admin panel using a staff account I got a message asking me to type the correct credentials for a staff account. The superuser credentials were not recognized when I tried to login as a regular user either. I ran migrations using the command python manage.py makemigrations; python manage.py migrate before creating the superuser and afterwards but every time I got a message saying that there are no migrations to apply. Can someone please help me fix this issue? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the [heroku cli](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) you can run this command to create a super user.

```sh
heroku login
heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser --app your-heroku-app-name
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I executed this command in heroku cli but I got the same error. I got a message saying the superuser has been successfully created but the credentials were not recognized. Does this have to do with applying migrations?

Comment: Admin might be asking email or username did you make sure you are not entering email when it is asking for username or vice versa?

Comment: Yes, I checked to make sure that I am entering the email and username where expected.